# Weird GCC warning/bug with a simple for loop when optimizations are enabled

Tags: c++, gcc

Consider the (extremely) minimal reproducible example here:

```
struct A
{
    char * data;
    std::size_t size;

    A(const char * d) : size{0}
    {
        if(d)
        {
            while(d[size++]);

            data = new char[size--]{}; // postfix because we keep the null-terminator (in data[size])
            std::memcpy(data, d, size);
        }
        else
            data = new char[size+1]{}; // Keep the null-terminator so that data[0] remains valid
    }
    ~A()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }
};
```

This structure basically copies a null-terminated string, keeps a null-terminator but does not count it into its `size` member.

Now if I write the following (loop over the `size` member):

```
int main()
{
    A a("Hello");

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < a.size; ++i)
        std::cout << 'x'; // Do whatever, it doesn't matter

    return 0;
}
```

If I enable the compiler optimizations, I get the following incomprehensible warning:

> ```
> In constructor 'A::A(const char*)',
>    inlined from 'int main()' at <source>:32:16:
> <source>:19:24: warning: 'void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)' writing between 9223372036854775808 and 18446744073709551614 bytes into a region of size between 1 and 9223372036854775807 [-Wstringop-overflow=]
>   19 |             std::memcpy(data, d, size);
>      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> <source>:18:37: note: destination object of size [1, 9223372036854775807] allocated by 'operator new []'
>   18 |             data = new char[size--]{}; // postfix because we keep the null-terminator (in data[size])
>      |
> ```

If I remove the `for` loop, everything's fine.
If I deactivate the compiler optimizations, everything's fine.

A more interesting thing is that if I write a `std::cout << whatever` **before** the `for` loop, everything's fine, but if I write it **after** the loop, the warning remains.
If I write something else than a `std::cout << whatever`, the warning still remains.

It smells the Undefined Behaviour so bad, but the code works exactly as expected and I see no issue with it.
I know the argument *"the code works exactly as expected"* doesn't stand when UB is involved, but in that specific case, if the warning message were true, it's very unlikely that I would get the expected results just by looking the incredibly big offsets shown (such invalid memory accesses would for sure trigger a segmentation fault).

Clang see no issue with that code sample and accepts it with or without optimizations enabled.

So my question is simple but probably hard to answer, what happens with GCC here ? Is the given code sample invalid ?

---

Here is a <kbd>[live example](https://godbolt.org/z/jcYoqx769)</kbd> of the issue.

Comment: Seems strange. If you output `size` after the `while` loop it shows `6`. If you replace the loop with `size = 6;` the warning disappears.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes it's normal that it is `6` after the `while` since we check against the null-terminator (which is the 6th element). But the loop is `size == 5`.

Comment: My comment is meant to highlight that hardcoding the variable to the value it has at runtime removes the warning. It looks like a false positive.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes but the real value to hardcode is `5` not `6` (I decrement size right after the while to not include the terminator in the `size`)

Comment: It seems the ``{}`` in ``data = new char[size--]{}; `` confuses gcc. If  you remove it the warning disappears.

Comment: @Fareanor Not if you replace the `while` loop with the value, since it has a value of 6 at that point.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh right, I thought you were talking about the for loop in main.

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich I can't remove it, otherwise it would be undefined behaviour. `{}` guarantees me default-initialization. But still the question remains :)

Comment: @Fareanor You don't actually want to zero initialize it, since you overwrite nearly the whole thing. You should just assign `'/0'` to the last element instead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes indeed, it would probably work, but I'm interested in that specific code sample, which IMHO is valid (and saves the last assignment, even if it's not a big deal).

Comment: `data = new char[size]; std::memcpy(data, d, size--);` is better optimized and eliminates that warning of the gcc static analyzer.

Comment: Obviously a gcc bug.

Comment: Use `std::strcpy` to copy a C-style string. No need to explicitly mess with the size or the nul terminator.

Comment: @273K This is what I did in the end :) But my concern wasn't really about finding a workaround solution but why this warning is emitted. But if it's a bug, it's a bug :)

Comment: The warning is emitted because such a hard to read code is even hard to analyze to a compiler.